# Sum of double array gets incorrect answer with e

Tags: c++, double

I am getting weird error with double elements sum, it looks like 1e+002, when answer is double sum.

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE =20;
//Index variable
int i;
//For finding average
double sum=0.00;
cout.precision(2);
srand((unsigned)time(0));
double main_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
//Header
cout << "Element number \t\t" << "Random Number\n\n" << endl;
//Assigning random values into array.
for (i=0; i< ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
{
//Randomizer
double ran =(rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(10-0)));
main_array[i] = ran;
sum+=main_array[i];
```

Comment: 1e+002 = 1*10^2 = 100  if it helps

Comment: Your algorithm appears to be random. What answer did you expect, and why do you think that the produced answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The letter `e` denotes [scientific](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/scientific/) notation. The presence of it does not make the value "incorrect".

Use the [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed) stream manipulator to specify fixed-point notation.

`cout << fixed << sum;`